# Is AdS repulsive?

Tags: general-relativity, cosmological-constant, anti-de-sitter-spacetime

Is Anti de Sitter spacetime repulsive because of its negative scalar curvature? Will a fluid flowing radially inward experience an opposition that has a radially outward component? And how can one quantify this "opposition"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AdS has a harmonic oscillator potential with the minimum located at the center. Consequently, it has a "attractive" type force. Objects tend to move to the center of AdS as they have less energy there.

de Sitter on the other hand has a repulsive potential and objects tend to move away.

Comment: can you suggest readings on this?